# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling from older version of db to new version

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

```
@Database(entities = {HoroscopeResponse.class, HoroscopeData.class, EmojiBean.class, DailyHoroscopeTimeStamp.class, WeeklyHoroscopeTimeStamp.class
        , MonthlyHoroscopeTimeStamp.class, YearlyHoroscopeTimeStamp.class}, version = 4, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class HoroscopeDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Horoscope_database";

    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "horoscope_database";
    private static HoroscopeDatabase sInstance;

    public static HoroscopeDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                Migration migration2_3 = new Migration(2,3) {
                    @Override
                    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'emoji_table' ('date' INTEGER NOT NULL,'emoji' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'month' TEXT NOT NULL,'year' TEXT NOT NULL,'day' TEXT NOT NULL,'beanpos' INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('id') ); ");
                    }
                };
                Migration migration1_2 = new Migration(1,2) {
                    @Override
                    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'horoscope_data' ADD COLUMN'rashiDescriptionEng' TEXT DEFAULT ''");
                    }
                };
                Migration migration3_4 = new Migration(3,4) {
                    @Override
                    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
                        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE 'emoji_table' RENAME COLUMN 'id' TO '_id'");
                    }
                };
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Creating new database instance");
                sInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        HoroscopeDatabase.class, HoroscopeDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                        .addMigrations(migration1_2)
                        .addMigrations(migration2_3)
                        .addMigrations(migration3_4)
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .build();
            }
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the database instance");
        return sInstance;
    }

}
```

I've got error(for migrating from older db app version otherwise it's fine) in creating emoji_table in migration 1_2
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'emoji_table'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is as it says. That is you have :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'emoji_table' ('date' INTEGER NOT NULL,'emoji' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'month' TEXT NOT NULL,'year' TEXT NOT NULL,'day' TEXT NOT NULL,'beanpos' INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('id') );
```

and there is NO **id** column for it to be used as the primary key.

Instead you want/need something like :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'emoji_table' ('id' INTEGER, 'date' INTEGER NOT NULL,'emoji' INTEGER NOT NULL, 'month' TEXT NOT NULL,'year' TEXT NOT NULL,'day' TEXT NOT NULL,'beanpos' INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ('id') );
```

With Room the Entity rules, so you need to ensure that the `EmojiBean.class` (I assume that's the correct Entity) does have a field/variable for **id**, although as you then rename the column in migration 3 to 4 the field/variable should be **_id** or have a @ColumnInfo annotation naming the column _id).

Comment: i don't think it's a solution cause i've tried that solution before